# Magento contact form disappears

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-form, google-map

We are facing an usual issue, when you go to https://gullybaba.magemojo.io/contacts/ and perfrom either of the below mention tasks

1. click on any blank area of the page(not on input fields)
   http://recordit.co/rdm5lC9JE6
2. scroll down http://recordit.co/DDGjPO4w3W

Any mouse movement on the contact form part, the form disappears. The issue is not related to google map, that we have tested with removed google map. Please advice how can we get rid of this issue.

Comment: check if you have added jQuery code to add `display: none` onclick to element with id `contactForm`

Comment: @Piyush where should i check it ?

Comment: you can check it in 
 `app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/contacts/form.phtml` or in any additional js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code and found it is due to `varienForm` function calling (might be issue there) or somewhere id `contactForm` is set to `display: none`.

For quick solution, just change id of from `contactForm` to "any diffrent name" like `contactForm23`.

Please do not make change in below code for testing purpose.

```
var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', false);
```

Also once you done testing with change, Please check with above code to apply same Id used in form.

Comment: Thanks Piyush & Amit, 'if i change the id in form tag & keep it "contactForm" in varian code will the form work.

Comment: @Mek it will cause in break of form validation

Comment: Thanks @Amit it was id that was causing the issue. But the validation is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in CSS its adding style="display: none;"

I think in form code section:

```
<form class="contact-form col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" action="https://gullybaba.magemojo.io/contacts/index/post/" id="contactForm" method="post" style="display: none;">
```

it's adding "display:none" , So issue is with **id="contactForm"**

Please check in JS file , there might be any code which applies display none on form ID.

Comment: Thanks @Sheshgiri for your post, but where do you see "display:none". I am not able to view it in form tag. https://prnt.sc/gmj212 . Please advice what should i look out for.

Comment: When your form disappearing check from 'inspect element'  in your form style:'display:none' css element is adding .